# Using mouse events in vbscript, how to declare routines

Tags: vba, vbscript

I'm trying to translate a vba macro into vbscripting. That macro works when executing it from Excel VB but it uses nothing from Excel.
When I convert

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" ( _
 ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
```

into

```
Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" ( _
 ByRef lpPoint)
```

I get an error: `wsf(15, 18) Error de compilación de Microsoft VBScript: Se esperaba un final de instrucción` (I'm working in spanish environment)

(15, 18) points to

```
Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" ( _
 ByRef lpPoint)
```

Is it possible to use mouse events in Vbscripting? If yes, how ought I to do it?

Comment: For user692942: Yes, I think your link answered my question. Thank you, very much.

Comment: For BigBen: I want to use VBS because the VB code I'm using don't need specific functions from Excel